# Individually change margins in QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, margins, qgridlayout

I have a QGridLayout containing mostly QLabels. It's a 3x10 grid and I want different margins on the content of each of the three columns. E.g. I want to be able to place my labels with a different amount of space to their grid border.

If I set the property `ContentMargins`, it just refers to everything in my grid.

How do I set content margins for a single column and for individual rows in a QGridLayout?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to set QGridLayout margins to 0. Add for each column a QVBoxLayout item, and set its margins.

Comment: Yes, this is not exactly an answer to my question, but it makes sense. In fact, maybe i should just make a QHBoxLayout and add three QVBoxLayouts to it. That way I can handle the QVBoxLayouts individually, like you say. Thank you.